# Closure and scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello.

```
 for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        let j = i; // yay, block-scope for closure!
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( j );
        }, j*1000 );
    }
```

This is a code snippet from "You Don't Know JS" series. I know that this wouldn't work as intended(the intention is to write each subsequent value of j with 1 second intervals) if there was a `var` instead of `let`. I know that for it to work the `timer` function needs to have a closure over scopes each of which contains a value from the set of values of `j`, for example:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
(function(j){
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( j );
    }, j*1000 );
})( i );
```

}

This makes sense for me as new scope is created for each iteration of the loop.
So my question is: does the variable declared with `let` inside the loop create a new scope for each iteration. Thanks.

Comment: The *variable* doesn't create a new scope; it's the block itself. The declaration of the variable takes advantage of that. And yes, each iteration has its own context; the trick would not work otherwise.

Comment: Sorry couldn't you explain this for a person new to javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ?? That *is* the explanation. Your own question indicates that you already understand how it works :)

Comment: :) I am confused now. Does it mean that with `var` there is one scope unlike `let` which creates new scope during each iteration. By the way what I understand, is that for this `timer` function to work the right way multiple scopes are needed in order to close over them.

Comment: And another little question: what is context and how is it different from scope. Thanks.

Comment: `var` declarations apply to the enclosing function. `let` declarations apply to the enclosing *block*. "Scope" is the formal word for "where is a variable visible". The term "context" is less formal (at least in JavaScript) but in my comment I meant the same thing. A scope is *sort-of* like an "invisible" object. You cannot directly refer to the scope, but `var` and `let` give you the ability to use it like you'd use an object and properties.